# Oracle performance issue Exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small application for schools and I face the next issue
I have a query on Oracle that supposed to fetch all teachers that has a specific student in there classes:

```
select * from teacher
where exists
 (
   select * from students 
   where teacher.teacher_id = students.teacher_id
     and lower(student_name) like '%john%'
 )
```

But my query is taking a long time, I tried to use IN or even JOIN but that didn't solve my problem:

```
select * from teacher
where teacher.teacher_id in
 (
   select students.teacher_id from students 
   where lower(student_name) like '%john%'
 )
```

and this is using JOIN:

```
select * from teacher
   JOIN 
      (select students.teacher_id from students 
      where lower(student_name) like '%john%') STUD
ON STUD.teacher_id = teacher_id
```

actually all are giving me the same result but I found that using EXISTS was the fastest
query, but still taking much time -about 10 min-.
I think that there might be a way using %rowtype and nested tables to solve the problem...
I am a beginner in Oracle, so if some body can help I will be graceful.

Comment: The data model looks odd. Each student appears to have a single teacher, unless the student table has multiple rows per student. If that's the case you need a table that is unique for each teacher, one that is unique for each student, and an intersection table between the two.

Comment: %rowtype is a PL/SQL construct, nothing to do with query performance. Nested tables are used to store object types in a table, also not relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct * from teacher 
join student on teacher.teacher_id = student.teacher_id 
where student_name ..
```

and there should be an index on teacher_id of student

Comment: on lower(student_name) as well